# Delete query on huge table taking long time with error lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql

In a stored procedure I am deleting records from a table which is having approx. 62,00,00,000 rows. Query to delete records in stored procedure is:

```
REPEAT
    DO SLEEP(2);
    DELETE FROM EXAM WHERE FKEXAMEVENTID=eventID ORDER BY ID LIMIT limit_cnt;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT()=0 END REPEAT;
```

`limit_cnt` is set to 10,000 and the rows to delete as per `WHERE` clause is 3,51,54,226.

When the execution starts I can see `system lock` state for long time and at the same time if I execute `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` then I found this

> ---TRANSACTION 1337539617, ACTIVE 24742 sec fetching rows mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 2865309 lock struct(s), heap size 296810024,
>   127249417 row lock(s), undo log entries 38722014 MySQL thread id
>   2088760, OS thread handle 0x7fdaa9fff700, query id 1714447623
>   com.prod.mysql 10.10.10. dbguru System lock DELETE FROM EXAM WHERE
>   FKEXAMEVENTID=eventID ORDER BY ID LIMIT limit_cnt

I can see `updating` state for very short period of time then again `system lock` state appears and after 6-7 hours. I get error `lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction`

How I can make delete process faster?

Comment: Just curious- How long does it take to delete 1 row? 10 rows? 100 rows? 1000 rows?

Comment: @Strawberry For 1 row = 0 Sec, 10 rows= 0.147 Sec, 100 rows = 1.035 Sec and for 1000 rows=7.005 Sec

Comment: So if you execute the 1000 row solution 10 times, you'll be done in a minute

Comment: @Strawberry Yes but the time which I given to you is a simple query `delete from tblname where primaryid=<value>` and in SP I am using `DELETE FROM EXAM WHERE FKEXAMEVENTID=eventID ORDER BY ID LIMIT limit_cnt`. So I guess limit is taking the most of time?

Comment: What is your mysql Version ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra 5.6

Comment: Could you please post table **EXAM** ?